# Spring cloud stream custom aggregator processor - Performance issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using a custom aggregator to aggregate correlated messages for my Spring cloud stream. I am using ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore as my message store.

The number of messages is of the order of 300-400k. I see considerable slowness with the aggregator when number of documents go above 70k. I tried scaling my aggregator instances. This helps briefly and then again it hits performance bottlenecks at some point. Now the problem with this slowness is that messages pile up in the queue eventually and when it hits Rabbit max-message-length, these messages are dropped by Rabbit.

I don't want to use SimpleMessageStore as it eventually leads to out of memory issues with the aggregator when the number messages are more than 90-100k. Also, a persistent message store gives me better resiliency.

Are there any suggestions as to how to tackle this slowness issue?

Comment: Can you profile the app to see where the bottleneck is? The store does create indexes on the collection so lookups shouldn't need to scan the collection.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell , I could see that the performance bottleneck is during reads. AggregatingMessageHandler calls store.getMessageGroup. And then while storing messages in the store, the messagestore calls findOne on the groupOrderQuery. Lastly, before returning the getMessageGroup another query is fired to findOne using the same groupOrderQuery. When I check MongoProfiler, I could see that reads are taking an average of 1900 msec while writes are taking an average of 80-200 msec once the number of documents go above 70k.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with a sorting? Why that is not a normal behavior when we try to deserialize so many records from the DB ?